What property ensures order of operations affects the result?
I'm trying to understand a property of binary operations where the order of applying the operation to a set of elements always matters. I'm not super advanced in math, but I will try to explain what I mean clearly.
Let's say we have a set of elements $[a, b, c, d]$, and we're performing some operation $* $ on them. What I'm curious about is when this operation is such that no matter how we group or order these elements, we never get the same result unless the order is exactly the same. For example, consider these different orderings:

$(a*b)*(c*d)$
$(c*d)*(a*b)$
$(b*a)*(d*c)$
$((a*b)*c)*d$

If $* $ is addition or multiplication of real numbers, all these different orderings give the same result because these operations are associative and commutative. If $* $ is instead subtraction or division, then the results can be different due to these operations being non-associative and non-commutative, e.g. $(a-b)-(c-d)\neq(c-d)-(a-b)$, but different orderings can also still get the same results, e.g. $(a-b)-(c-d)=(a-c)-(b-d)$.
What I'm curious about is if there's a specific term for operations where no two different orderings ever yield the same result. Is there a name for this property or other related properties that cause this? Or maybe a better way to describe what I'm thinking about? I'd love to learn more about this and explore some examples, but I'm not sure what to look up.
Thanks so much for any help or guidance you can offer!

Do you have any examples of such operations?  Where do they arise naturally?

The name of the property making the order unimportant is "commutativity" : you have mentiooned it ! It suffices to have commutativity for two elements $a * b = b * a$ to have it for any number and order of elements.

I don't have a good example of what I'm looking for. I have some ideas but lack the mathematical knowledge needed to verify or dismiss them. I started thinking about this since I came across multivariate functions used in cryptography where this property of having different results for different orderings is important. I was curious if there might be a simpler, more fundamental binary operation in mathematics that exhibits this same property.

@JeanMarie  OP wants the order to matter, though.  Every single time, in fact.

Relevant: Nick J. Lord, Non-associative operations, Mathematics Magazine 60 #3 (June 1987), pp. 174-177. See also my 12 September 2006 sci.math post "Combinatorics of associativity", especially the stuff about associativity rank, power associativity (i.e. associativity issues when $a=b=c=d=\ldots),$ etc.

@Randall : do you mean that the context is a commutative operation which isn't necessarily associative ?

@DaveL.Renfro Yes, the unlimited non-associativity they describe looks very relevant! Interesting read. I don't get any other search results when I search for it though, so I take it this is not standard terminology?

$\ldots$ so I take it this is not standard terminology? --- I doubt this is something sufficiently written about to have standard terminology, but the phrase "unlimited non-associativity" is a lot more self-explanatory than many terms and phrases used in mathematics and thus seems like a good phrase to use until/if you discover something more standard. By the way, I'm not any kind of expert on this topic. The topic is simply one of many (hundreds?) topics that, over the last several decades, (continued)

I've accumulated photocopies of papers on for various personal reasons (within the past 10-15 years, it's been mostly hardcopy print-outs or even just digital files), and which when the opportunity presents itself AND I have the free time AND I have the interest, I'll post summaries and bibliographic lists for those who might be interested, such as that 2006 sci.math post.
